# how can I get android filesystem size in bytes from adb shell?

Tags: android, shell

If I run from android shell the `df` command I get the sizes of all filesystems in human readable numbers. It seems that the command doesn't take any options (e.g. `-something`).

I want to get the exact size of the filesystem (in bytes).

I know I can get the sizes by creating an app which uses statfs. Is there any OTHER WAY to do it (via command)?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, as long as busybox is installed. (And if not, you could prompt the user to install it.)

You can use

```
busybox df -B 1
```

to get a report in bytes.